# Deselect Items from SwiftUI List on macOS with single click

Tags: list, macos, swiftui, selection

I'm developing a macOS App with a `List` View with selectable rows.
As there is unfortunately no `editMode`

[image]

on macOS, Single Click Selection of Cells is possible, but deselecting an already selected Cell doing the same does nothing.
The only option to deselect the Cell is to `CMD + Click` which is not very intuitive.
Minimum Example:

```swift
struct RowsView: View {
    
    @State var selectKeeper: String?
    
    let rows = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
    
    var body: some View {
        List(rows, id: \.self, selection: $selectKeeper) { row in
            Text(row)
        }
    }
}

struct RowsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RowsView()
    }
}
```

Clicking Row Nr 3 with a Single Click or even double Click does nothing and the row stays selected.
[image: Clicking Row Nr 3 with a Single Click or even double Click does nothing.]

---

**Attaching Binding directly**
I have tried to attach the `Binding` directly as described in the excelent answer for a `Picker` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68428304/5392813), but this does not seem to work for `List` on macOS:

```swift
...
    var body: some View {
        List(rows, id: \.self, selection: Binding($selectKeeper, deselectTo: nil)) { row in
            Text(row)
        }
    }
...

public extension Binding where Value: Equatable {
                
    init(_ source: Binding<Value>, deselectTo value: Value) {
        self.init(get: { source.wrappedValue },
                  set: { source.wrappedValue = $0 == source.wrappedValue ? value : $0 }
        )
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how single click deselect can be made possible without rebuilding the selection mechanism?

<sup>For the record: XCode 13.2.1, macOS BigSur 11.6.2</sup>

Comment: To confirm, do you want single selection or multiple selection of cells/rows?

Comment: Multi Selection, but i bootstrapped the Example to make it easier.
It is not working in either way

Answer (score 2):

We can block default click handling by using own gesture and manage selection manually.

Here is demo of possible approach. Tested with Xcode 13.2 / macOS 12.1

[image: demo]

```
struct RowsView: View {

    @State var selectKeeper: String?

    let rows = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]

    var body: some View {
        List(rows, id: \.self, selection: $selectKeeper) { row in
            Text(row)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())      // handle click row-wide
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())    // remove default edges
                .onTapGesture {
                    selectKeeper = selectKeeper == row ? nil : row   // << here !!
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 4)          // look&feel like default
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost perfect, thank you,
I have colored the cells so that the missing, non clickable part is easy to see:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFldR.jpg
Unfortunatelly this is the hardest part to fit as it is beyond the frame of the cells.

Answer (score 0):

I refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57023746/1883707) to a SO post titled "[Select Multiple Items in a SwiftUI List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57022615/select-multiple-items-in-swiftui-list)".

From this answer I generated code to select multiple items in a list.

In my sample code I use a checkmark to illustrate whether a row is selected, but you could change this to suit your needs.

You'll need to change your `@State` wrapper to a `Set`, because you confirmed that you'll need to select a group of items. (An aside, Apple recommends that you mark `@State` property wrappers as `private` so as to reinforce their intended use locally.)

```
@State private var selectedItems: Set<String>?
let rows = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
var body: some View {
    List(rows, id: \.self) { item in            
        RowSelectable(selectedItems: $selectedItems, rowItem: item)
    }
}
```

where `RowSelectable` is...

```
struct RowSelectable: View {
    @Binding var selectedItems: Set<String>?
    var rowItem: String
    var isSelected: Bool {
        return selectedItems?.contains(rowItem) == true
    }
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(rowItem)
            if selectedItems?.contains(rowItem) == true {
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
            if self.isSelected {
                selectedItems!.remove(rowItem)
            }
            else {
                selectedItems!.insert(rowItem)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this yet, so let me know if it doesn't work and I'll check in Xcode.